# CheckBox onCheckedListener not working DataBinding

Tags: android, android-databinding

Im trying to listen when the checkbox is checked or not.

**Problem**

`onCheckedListener` is never called

**What have i tried**

XML

```
<CheckBox
   android:onCheckedChanged="@{(v, checked) -> handler.onCheckedChanged(checked)}"
   ...
 />

<variable
    name="handler"
    type="com.example.tiago.demo.Search.Adapter.Adapter"/>
```

Adapter.java (`com.example.tiago.demo.Search.Adapter`)

```
public void onCheckedChanged(boolean isCheck){
    Log.d("adapter","Is checked: ".concat(String.valueOf(isCheck)));
}
```

I read similar posts about this on forums and in here, but none of them work for me, this one is the only one that lets me compile with no problems, but when i click on the checkbox i don't get any log message.

**Notes**

- i get an error in this line `android:onCheckedChanged` unknown attribute (all the examples that i see use `onCheckedChanged` not sure why im getting this message)
- `onCheckedChanged` color is yellow the only place i call this is from xml

Comment: have you set handler from your adapter or activity?

Comment: what do you mean?, i have the `onCheckedChanged` this is only a method i have it inside the adaper i don't have it on the activity.

Comment: yes but from adapter binding you need to use setHandler() to set handler variable. Can you post your adapter code where you are using binding?

Comment: i need to learn more about this, it's working now, thanks alot for pointing me for the binding

Comment: You may use the answer box below. And use the checkmark to accept it. Or you can let @RaviRupareliya provide the answer

Comment: I'm on my phone now I will do that tomorrow when I'm on my laptop thanks once again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix my issue, i was not binding the variable silly mistake

Comment: how you do that?

Comment: @RonelGonzales binding.setHandler(this), handler is the variable name in the xml